# JQmobile web application goes to previous page on click events

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-mobile

I'm building a php based mobile application using jqmobile and jquery. I have buttons that submit form without reloading the page using jquery's $.post method and the returned data is displayed using a pop up window which can be closed by clicking the ok button or programatically after 2600ms. My issue is that some times when the button is click the form is submitted and the pop up appers and closes itself but the page redirects itself to the previous page. My script is located at the bottom of the page after

```
        $(document).ready(function () {     
      $('.quickadd').click(function () {

    var dataidd = $(this).attr("href");
        var order_formm = $("form#quick_order"+dataidd);
        var responseVar = $('#alert');

        $.post("add_order.php", order_formm.serialize(), function (data) {

            responseVar.html(data);
            $("#alert").trigger("create");
            $("#alert").popup("open", {
                positionTo: '#showalert'
            });


        });

        return false;
       });
    });
```

Comment: There is no redirect code here... are you sure that when you click on a button you're not triggering a touch event that also "clicks" a back button somewhere? Is the back button near the dialog's OK button?

Comment: Add `data-history=false` to your popup div.